# SSE Matrix Multiplication NxN. Why is this error

Tags: c, x86, sse, matrix-multiplication, simd

I am beginner using SSE instructions, and I try to implement MMM. So, I implemented MMM using matriz 2by2, now I want to implement MMM using matrix NXN

```
#include <emmintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void simd_2x2(int lda, double *A, double *B, double *C)
{
    __m128d a, b1, c1;
    for (int k = 0; k < lda; k++) {
        //printf("%f\n",C[k * lda]);
        c1 = _mm_loadu_pd(C + k * lda);   //load unaligned block in C
        //c2 = _mm_loadu_pd(C + 1 * lda);
        for (int i = 0; i < lda; ++i) {
            a = _mm_load_pd(A + i * lda);//load aligned i-th column of A
            b1 = _mm_load1_pd(B + i + k * lda); //load i-th row of B
            //b2 = _mm_load1_pd(B + i + 1 * lda);
            c1 = _mm_add_pd(c1, _mm_mul_pd(a, b1)); //rank-1 update
            //c2 = _mm_add_pd(c2, _mm_mul_pd(a, b2));
        }
        _mm_storeu_pd(C + k * lda, c1);   //store unaligned block in C
        //_mm_storeu_pd(C + 1 * lda, c2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 2;
    double *buf = NULL;
    buf = (double *)malloc(3 * n * n * sizeof(double));

    double *A = buf + 0;
    double *B = A + n * n;
    double *C = B + n * n;

    simd_2x2(n, A, B, C);

    return 0;
}
```

When `n=2` everything work fine:

```
A = 4.000000  3.000000  
    2.000000  4.000000  

B = 1.000000  3.000000  
    2.000000  4.000000  

C = 0.000000  0.000000  
    0.000000  0.000000 

C = C + A * B = 10.000000  24.000000  
                10.000000  22.000000
```

but if `n=4` I get the next:

```
A = 4.000000  0.000000  1.000000  4.000000  
    2.000000  1.000000  4.000000  0.000000  
    3.000000  1.000000  2.000000  1.000000  
    4.000000  1.000000  3.000000  1.000000  

B = 1.000000  5.000000  9.000000  13.000000  
    2.000000  6.000000  10.000000  14.000000  
    3.000000  7.000000  11.000000  15.000000  
    4.000000  8.000000  12.000000  16.000000  

C = 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
    0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  

C = C + A * B = 23.000000  59.000000  95.000000  131.000000  
                16.000000  44.000000  72.000000  100.000000  
                 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  
                 0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

**The last two rows are not calculated, why is this? Can someone help me?**

I have almost 5 days reading about SSE but I can not fully understand and neither solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It looks like you need another (innermost) loop. For n = 2 you get lucky because there are two doubles per vector. For n > 2 you need to iterate over the number of vectors per row (e.g. 2 vectors for n = 4). For odd n you also need some scalar code to handle the last element of each row.